# Hexadecimals addition end result is always wrong? C++

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, memory-address

When I want to calculate the address of a function, I do the following:

```
HMODULE base = GetModuleHandle(L"program.exe"); // Module base addr

// Adding an offset to the base
std::cout << (base + 0x8F0A0) << std::endl; -> Wrong!
```

I'm not sure why the result is wrong. I've tested it via online hex calcs and also have debugger to check both values.

Could base be considered decimal and other being hex, produce wrong results?

How can I get a result in hex?

Comment: Why do you think that result is wrong?

Comment: "Could base be considered decimal and other being hex" neither, they are both binary.

Comment: How do you want the result to appear? Are you expecting `cout` to print in hex? Try `std::cout << std::hex << ...`

Comment: Yeah I would like to receive the result in hex.

Comment: Hex isn't a property of ints, it's just a representation of an int.

Comment: Hex, decimal, octal, binary or *any other base* doesn't matter. It's just maths -regardless of what base(s) you are working with it is all just numbers.

Comment: The code you've shown is invalid. You cannot perform integer arithmetic on an `HMODULE` value. So you have to have a cast in there somewhere that you aren't showing us. If you're truncating the value, that would explain why you're getting the wrong result. If you're *not* truncating the value, then this is non-reproducible. Integer arithmetic is not b0rken in C++, I can guarantee that much.

Comment: If it's the addition not working, then `GetModuleHandle` is irrevelevant and your [mcve] can do without it. You might find that it works once you try to get rid of it, but I guarantee that no Windows-specific things need to be there, and that's easy to see by observing that the call can be replaced by a value.

Comment: @CodyGray, It actually depends whether `STRICT` is defined as to whether it's a `void*`, and it seems `STRICT` is defined in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681(v=vs.85).aspx), depending on whether `STRICT` is defined, `HMODULE` is essentially either a `void*` or a `<unique type>*`, the purpose of this being to make each handle type a different C++ type, meaning compiler errors when you mix and match. In the former case, pointer arithmetic won't compile. In the latter case, it will compile, but you can't rely on anything happening because pointer arithmetic takes the type's size into account and because pointer arithmetic is undefined if you leave the object/array being pointed to.

You should treat this pointer as pointing to nothing in particular, and therefore not do pointer arithmetic. You have to `reinterpret_cast` it to an integral type that you're sure is large enough (`std::uintptr_t`) and then do arithmetic on that integral value.

In my local header, this unique type contains an `int` member, so adding 1 will actually move the pointer ahead by 4 bytes (you know, except for the undefined behaviour and all). It just so happens that 0x00DE0000 + 4 * 0x8F0A0 is your 0x0101C280 value.

Answer (score 1):

You're problem lies with the value `GetModuleHandle(L"program.exe")` returning: `00DE0000`. You need to utilise C hexadecimal syntax, so you need to add and precede "0x" to your hex number **00DE0000**.

**Hence, your base number should be casted to a numeric value: `0x00DE0000`**

```
0x00DE0000 is equal to 00DE0000
```

Try using `std::string to_string(int value);` to convert it to string, then convert your hex values (base) to C hexadecimal syntax (add "0x" at the beginning of your hex value). To finish off, convert your base value back to a numeric value (e.g. use [**std::stoi**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)) and perform the addition using [**std::hex**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex).

---

**Try this code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57598a3e2be18fff).**

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    int hex1 = 0x8F0A0;
    int hex2 = 0x00DE0000; // Using int values

    std::cout << std::hex << hex1 + hex2 << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used DWORD* before, but I just don't really understand why the base + 0x8F0A0 returns a completely wrong value than the target func adress is. (With DWORD* now)

Comment: Have you checked what your hex value "base" contains, before adding it? Also, have you tried using GetModuleHandle(nullptr)?

Comment: Yeah, the base is (00DE0000) and I'm adding 0x8F0A0, it returns (0101C280)... which is wrong.

Comment: I have tried DWORD_PTR just now and the result was same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141778/discussion-between-user54264611634646244-and-j-doe).

Comment: Just to be clear, there's nothing magical about `DWORD_PTR`. It's just an unsigned integer value (like a `DWORD` is) that is guaranteed to be the same size as a pointer. That is what the `_PTR` suffix on Windows data types *always* means. You could just as easily cast to `std::uintptr_t`. Aside from that, this answer tends to confuse the issue because of sloppy wording around the issue of hex values. Hexadecimal is just a *representation*, it doesn't change the nature of the value.

Comment: @CodyGray By all means feel free to edit to improve wording.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris has said, I had the same case, solving the thing like this:

```
int offset = 0x8F0A0;
std::uintptr_t base = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(GetModuleHandle(L"program.exe"));

// Here added 4 bytes to the offset.

std::cout << std::hex << (base + (offset + 4096)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: You still seem confused about hex vs. decimal. The pointer value is neither inherently hex nor decimal. The reinterpret cast takes the bits that are currently being interpreted as a pointer (which is often expressed in hex, but is just an integer value) and reinterprets them as a `uintptr_t`, which is an integral type. `0xF` and `15` are two ways of specifying exactly the same thing: an `int` with the **value** 15. And all `std::hex` does is tell the output stream to represent the **value** as hex.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I'm starting to understand that better :)

Comment: On that note, [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W3xI1HJUy7Q) might help. Around [17 minutes in](https://i.imgur.com/HHNLQ4r.png) in particular.

Comment: Appreciate :) Thanks!